# React JS: Mixing data types for one state property

Tags: data-types, state, reactjs

In the spirit of minimising state I always have a desire to mix data types for a given state property. For instance, if I were creating a React page that rendered a list of items that could either be the entire list of items, or a filtered list of items, I might want to have a state property called `itemList` and another one called `filteredItemList`.

Now in `filteredItemList` I might want to differentiate between a filter query **returning no results** vs the `filteredItemList` being empty because a filter is not currently 'set'.

I'm thinking I could set `filteredItemList` to the string `"no filter active"` when a filter isn't active. I could also set it as an array with 0 elements when a filter is active but returned zero results. And lastly, if a filter is active and does have results, it would be an array with a length greater than 0.

Doing this, I could test for this property's string value, and/or its array length, to determine what and how to render.

I am thinking that one benefit to doing this would be to obviously minimise the amount of state properties.

I am wondering if there are any inevitable drawbacks to doing something like this?